# Make multiple API request parallel and show the data as soon as we receive any one response in asp.net

Tags: multithreading, asynchronous, threadpool

I am building a hotel search engine where I have 20 xml API integration. Now facing a problem of time laps in receiving all 20 xml responses from all API before binding the result page. I am looking for a solution where we can call all API parallel in multithreading and I want to show the api response as soon as I receive 1st response from any API and then merge next response from previous one and update the binding page. In this way I can show result of 1st few hotels starting from very 1st API response. 
Please suggest me the way I can achieve my objective in asp.net c#. This is my 1st question in this forum and very eager to have feedback.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to use javascript to display the responses fluently. Basically, have ASP.NET load an empty page then use javascript to call the 20 API endpoints. As the responses come in, update the display. Single page application (SPA) frameworks, such as [Angular](https://angularjs.org/), are fantastic for these situations.

Comment: Hi Matt. Thanks for your answer. Can you explain more by giving one example in angular js to achieve the solution.

Comment: It's a bit complicated to give an example here. This tutorial does a great job explaining what I am talking about. http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/build-a-single-page-application-spa-with-aspnet-web-api-and-angularjs